# Get posts associated with media attachment

Tags: php, posts, query, attachments, media

Is there a good way to find all posts that contain a specific image?
I'm working on the attachment single template, and I'd like to list the posts that contain that image.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy way would be to just run a search on your Wordpress site on the name of the image. E.g. *your-image.png*. This should return a list of all the posts which have that image in it.